# 1973 F100 360 FE 5.9L Stalls when put in gear

Tags: ford, rough-idle, stall, f100

I've got a 73 F100 with a 360 FE and a C6 transmission. It idles fine but stalls when put in gear, with somewhat of a jump. New holley carb on it. Any idea why? I've also notice the idle speed going down quite a bit when in park after I give it a good rev... Is that related?

Thanks for any help

EDIT: no vacuum leaks :/

Comment: You need to check for a vacuum leak. Make sure you've plugged all of the ports along the bottom of the carb. This sounds like a pretty large one. Did you ensure the other end of the vacuum line going to the power booster (assuming there is one) on the brakes is plugged in?

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice, is there a power booster on manual brakes?